# Python with unit-tests in teamcity

Tags: python, unit-testing, teamcity, python-module

I like to run unit-tests during Teamcity build. I configure this step in the build like pytest with arguments test/unit/*.py. During this run I have "ModuleNotFoundError" for a module that I am actually testing. So my guess is that somehow the tree structure or working directory is changing.
So my working tree looks like that:

```
pipeline ---> __init__.py (empty file)
pipiline ---> model.py
```

inside this file I have this definition

```
 class Model():
```

The test folders are following:

```
test ---> unit ---> test_model.py
```

inside test_model.py I have:

```
from model import Model
```

During the run I have

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

I guess I should somehow define the Model class like dll, but I do not understand how to do this in Python.